# Linear algorithm to find two points with at least half diameter distance in a point set

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I am stuck with the following homework problem:

> Consider a point set P in the plane with |P| = n and let D(P) the diameter of P, i.e. the maximum Euclidean distance between any two points in P. I am tasked to find an algorithm of O(n) time that on input of P returns two points x and y of P with d(x,y) >= D(P)/2, where d denotes the Euclidean distance.

I have no idea how I could do that. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Any point is at least that far from at least one of the two points in the diameter...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not follow you. We can not assume that D(P) is given, the algortihm ONLY input is P and computing D(P) takes O(n log(n)) time

Comment: If it's even further from some other point, so much the better.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly. We pick some arbitrary point, say x, and then we compute d(x,y) for all the other points y in P. We then just pick the y with the greatest d(x,y), correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your points are `(xi,yi)`

1. find point with `min(xi)` with `O(n)` and name it `minX_point`
2. find point with `max(xi)` with `O(n)` and name it `maxX_point`
3. find point with `min(yi)` with `O(n)` and name it `minX_point`
4. find point with `max(yi)` with `O(n)` and name it `maxY_point`

now consider rectangle which boxes these 4 point (with horizontal and vertical edges)
the diameter of this rectangle is bigger or equal to D(P) because all of P points are boxed in it.
the diameter of rectangle is as following
`Rec_Diameter=sqrt((minX-maxX)^2+(minY-maxY)^2)`
now find `max((mixX-maxX),(minY-maxY))`
the maximum would be your desired point for example `maxX_point` and `minX_point`
because if the distance be less than `D(P)/2` then we have
`Rec_Diameter=sqrt((minX-maxX)^2+(minY-maxY)^2) < sqrt((D(P)/2)^2+(D(P)/2)^2)=D(P)/sqrt(2)` which `Rec_Diameter>=D(P) < D(P)/sqrt(2)` is not true